# How to list all projects, classes that have no dependents in solution in VS?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, resharper

How can I list all the projects (or maybe classes, interfaces etc. as well) that are not used or that have not dependents in the solution, in Visual Studio 2010 that has ReSharper installed?

Comment: Take a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4646270/205859) for unused types.

Comment: Regarding Resharper, they include `Inspect-CodeIssues In Solution`. Run that and... if the class or interface is not public, they will report it under `Redundancies in Symbol Declarations` but if the class/method is public they don't report it because it could be used from the outside of the solution.